# knockout data-bind text to function is returning stringified version of function

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-2.0

I'm using knockout with a foreach loop, and my specific element i want to bind the text element of  a span to an anonymous function, however there is just a string version of the function returned
`<span data-bind="text: function(ri) { ri.itemNameAndRateplan() + ' ' + ri.Adults(); }"></span>`

when run returns function `(ri){ ri.itemNameAndRateplan() +' '+ ri.Adults();}` as the html for the element. 
I would expect it to be something like `ratePlanNameValue 4`

How do i fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can actually just write `data-bind="text: ri.itemNameAndRateplan() +' '+ ri.Adults()"` If `ri` is an observable, add `()`. If this isn't the case I'd need to see some more code.

Comment: This is an example, I want the result to be a bit more complex with more properties included than  this, which is why I want to use the anonymous function. ri is an observable object

Comment: @mcgowan.b I would add a computed to the `ri` object, and just bind it. Writing extensive JS in a binding is just asking for problems. I've been down that road. I wouldn't recommend it.